# Implementing dynamic shadow in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am working on implementing Dynamic shadow(for a moving truck) in OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS platform.  I need idea regarding shaders used for implementing shadows & illustration code for dynamic shadows.

Comment: This is a rather broad question, since there are many different ways to realize dynamic shadows and you won't get around delving into the basics and then asking specific questions when implementing these. A starting point would be Google, with the keywords "shadow volume" or "shadow mapping" for the two major techniques, with the latter being the most widely used with all its modern specializations and improvements and also the easiest to get working in its simplest form.

Comment: Can I get sone links of examples/part of code for the same??

Comment: Well, delve into the general concepts and understand them and then look for examples and then you can come back asking specific questions instead of a "can I haz teh codes for dynamic shadows on iPhone"-question. Googling "shadow mapping" would really be a start on this. Then you can add "ES" or "OpenGL" keywords to the search.